# Problems with running python files including HTML on localhost or command line

Tags: python, html, cgi

I have a very simple python file including some HTML Code. It is supposed to just print out "Hallo" when run in the command line, and when opened in the Browser there should be a formatted HTML. Instead either way all it does is print the raw html-code.
Also IntelliJ says "unresolved reference 'print' ".
Any ideas, what is going wrong here?
I've added CGI configurations to https.conf, too.

Comment: how are you opening python code in a web browser?

Comment: I created a .py file and put it in my localhost folder, and running apache opened it

Answer (score 0):

Okay, there were some misconfigurations with the CGI. It was not interpreting the files in my MacBook "Sites" Folder, which I configured as my resource. Thus I had to change this in the https.conf:
here, both LoadModules needed to be active (#removed)

```
<IfModule !mpm_prefork_module>
    LoadModule cgid_module libexec/apache2/mod_cgid.so
</IfModule>
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    LoadModule cgi_module libexec/apache2/mod_cgi.so
</IfModule>
```

then there came an internal server error, when opening the .py in the browser. the logfile said:

```
 [Tue Dec 01 22:34:47.904341 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 1800] [client
 ::1:51615] End of script output before headers: test.py, referer:
 http://localhost/~zehra/
```

I configured the CGI through changing http.conf , so it interpreted everything from my Sites folder as cgi.That worked.

Still, it doesn't work in the command line nor IntelliJ.